# Fail connect remote jupyter notebook server possibly caused by chrome install

Tags: server, google-chrome, python3, jupyter, selenium

I'm trying to connect to jupyter notebook running on my remote server. The code below has been working fine for days to forward the jupyter notebook running on the port on my ubuntu server to my mac. It stopped recently.

It seemed to stop around the time I tried installing chrome on my ubuntu server along with chromedriver so I could use it with selenium.  I’m not sure if they’re related or not.  The post related to issues I was having with chrome and crhomedriver, and what I tried to do on ubuntu to resolve them are below:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681005/chrome-fails-on-ubuntu-server-with-selenium?noredirect=1#comment98046496_55681005
```

and the past post I have related to the jupyter notebook issue is below:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700615/connection-failed-to-remote-jupyter-notebook
```

Does anyone know what the issue might be?  And can you suggest a fix?  Also is there a way to just open the port for jupyter notebook so I wouldn't need to use

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 username@111.111.11.122
```

At work when we connect to jupyter notebook running on remote server we’d just type “servername:8889” into the web browser.  Since we were on the same network it would connect.

Also recently I tried shutting down and restarting my ubuntu server but it didn't fix anything, still can't connect remotely to the jupyter notebook server.

Ubuntu code:

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 username@111.111.11.122
```

Ubuntu code:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888
```

Message:

```
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
[I 14:11:23.334 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 2 kernels found
[I 14:11:23.343 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /run/user/1000/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 14:11:24.175 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/username
[I 14:11:24.175 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 14:11:24.175 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=d111b8540568567c80796a3be5cf53229fe38360b411a4dd
[I 14:11:24.175 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 14:11:24.178 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///run/user/1000/jupyter/nbserver-77790-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=d111b8540568567c80796a3be5cf53229fe38360b411a4dd
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for here is --ip.
You can connect to the remote computer directly by specifying the hostname when you start the server. 
[jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8232 --ip=ubuntu-pi-100000 ~/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqF3p.png)

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html
NotebookApp.allow_remote_accessBool
Default: False

Allow requests where the Host header doesn’t point to a local server

By default, requests get a 403 forbidden response if the ‘Host’ header shows that the browser thinks it’s on a non-local domain. Setting this option to True disables this check.

This protects against ‘DNS rebinding’ attacks, where a remote web server serves you a page and then changes its DNS to send later requests to a local IP, bypassing same-origin checks.

Local IP addresses (such as 127.0.0.1 and ::1) are allowed as local, along with hostnames configured in local_hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that I needed to type localhost:8888 in to the browser on my local machine. I had been typing in the port I opened the jupyter notebook server on, on my remote machine so localhost:8889. Example

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

followed by

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 username@111.111.11.122
```

bang head here.